# GStreamer: Struggling with GST_OBJECT in C++

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have started to take a look into GStreamer 1.0 in the last days. The first examples worked fine but now I am at a point where I need `GST_OBJECT(obj)`.
When I try to compile the example using it, the compiler `outputs undefined reference to symbol 'g_type_check_instance_cast'`. I am using Eclipse Luna for compiling. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, as a compiler I use GCC. In Eclipse I have added
 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include` 
`/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0` 
`/usr/include/glib-2.0`
to the include paths of the C++ Compiler and 
`glib-2.0`
`gstnet-1.0`
`gstbase-1.0`
`gstcheck-1.0`
`gstreamer-1.0`
`gstcontroller-1.0`
to the GCC C++ Linker libraries. I am new to adding external libraries to C++ so I have no idea while the compiler fails.

Short code snippet I have used:
`#include <iostream>`
`#include <gst/gst.h>`

`using namespace std;`

`int main(int argc, char **argv) {`
    GstElement *myFirstElement;

```
gst_init(&argc, &argv);

myFirstElement = gst_element_factory_make("fakesrc", "source");

if(!myFirstElement)
    return -1;

gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(myFirstElement));

return 0;
```

}`

Comment: Could you please include the part of code that calls GST_OBJECT(obj)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if I compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GstElement *myFirstElement;

  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  myFirstElement = gst_element_factory_make("fakesrc", "source");

  if(!myFirstElement)
      return -1;

  gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(myFirstElement));

  return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++ -o main main.cc  `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

everything works fine. Might be a problem with your setup...

Comment: Okay in this way it also works on my machine but I would like to do the compiling directly in Eclipse. So it seems that my configuration is not correct. Any ideas what I have to add to get it running?

Comment: Ok, so what pkg-config does is giving you the includes (on my system "pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0" -> "-pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include") and the library flags (using the "--libs" option instead) which you have to add. One hacky way would be to paste this   into eclipse. You might want to read this "http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_libpath.htm" on the topic

Comment: The compilers output of Eclipse is: g++ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test3.d" -MT"src/Test3.d" -o "src/Test3.o" "../src/Test3.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Test3.cpp
 
Building target: GStreamTest2
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "GStreamTest2"  ./src/GStreamTest2.o ./src/Test2.o ./src/Test3.o   -lglib-2.0 -lgstnet-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstcheck-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgstcontroller-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/Test3.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_type_check_instance_cast'

Comment: The relevant symbol ('g_type_check_instance_cast') is in libgobject-2.0. You could add "-lgobject-2.0" to the linker. On my system, "pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0" returns "-lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0" so once again it *should* work...

Comment: Thanks. "gobject-2.0" was missing in the libaries section. Now it works. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

g_type_check_instance_cast is included in the library gobject-2.0.
So make sure that the library is linked.

I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be the linking order of the libraries. When linking libraries, the order actually matter. For example, if libA requires symbol from libB, then you need to link in the order of -lA -lB. If you reverse the order then the linking would fail.

My guess is that if you linked glib before gstreamer then it would fail, as gstreamer depends on symbols from glib.

Comment: Well, if the required libgobject-2.0 is not added to the linker at all, then the linking will fail. This does not seem like a problem of ordering to me.